# How to send SMS to the server in windows phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, sms, web

I have a requirement to send SMS to the web server from my application. The scenario is this:  user will fill a form and send the information through the SMS to the our web server because we want the details of the person who is using the application for our database.
My application is simple text writing application.how can i do this because i haven't work for web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send an SMS from your app you will need to use the [SMSComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394005%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). The user will see the full number of the server and the contents of the message. The user will be able to cancel the sending of the SMS.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to send a POST request to your server, and then your server will send the actual SMS, as a free/paid service?

Simply use HTTP POST with the WebClient. Scott Hanselman [wrote a guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx)